# How to list user services of another user under ubuntu

Tags: systemd, services

There is the usual command for listing the systemd services:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

Then there is the --user parameter for enabling and starting a user service, executing the command from a user's session:

```
systemctl --user enable/start <service name>
```

I need, as root, to list services running under a certain user, something like:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --user <username>
```

Haven't been able to find anything about this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, it isn't so easy to do because you have to have access to user's DBUS. I would really like to have simple command to list all services includes services of all users in the system, but it probably isn't possible now.

Anyway there is easy way on **Systemd >= 248** for doing exactly what you want, if you have specific user you want to list services for.

#### Systemd >= 248

```sh
systemctl --user --machine=<username>@ list-units --type=service
```

This is probably working in similar way as `machinectl` in [answer by @Erik Sjölund](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300162/127868)

#### Systemd < 248

```sh
runuser -l <username> -c 'systemctl --user list-units --type=service'
```

#### Bonus: List services from all users

Here is uggly parody to oneliner which will list all user services from all users on the system. I just glued it up - no promises it is bullet proof.

For systemd **>= 248**:

```sh
while read -r username; do echo $username: ; systemctl --user --machine=$username@ list-units --type=service --no-legend; done < <(ps axo user:100,args | awk '$2 == "/lib/systemd/systemd" && $3 == "--user" { print $1 }' | sort -u)
```

And for older ones:

```sh
while read -r username; do echo $username: ; runuser -l "$username" -c 'systemctl --user list-units --type=service --no-legend'; done < <(ps axo user:100,args | awk '$2 == "/lib/systemd/systemd" && $3 == "--user" { print $1 }' | sort -u)
```

It simply find all `/lib/ssytemd/systemd --user` processes in the systemd, take user under which they are running and use that user for `list-units` commands above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, but by using `sudo`. Read `man sudo sudoers`, and

```
sudo -u theuser systemctl ...
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This will not work because `sudo` will not set the necessary environment variables. For a workaround, see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347560/5637701). Do prefer `systemctl -M` or `machinectl` if they are available.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `machinectl` command like this:

```
machinectl shell <username>@ /usr/bin/systemctl --user list-units --type=service --quiet
```

Here is an example with the local account *erikdev* on my computer.

```
[root@laptop ~]# machinectl shell erikdev@ /usr/bin/systemctl --user list-units --type=service --quiet
Connected to the local host. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service loaded active exited Create User's Volatile Files and Directories

Connection to the local host terminated.
[root@laptop ~]#
```

I'm running **Systemd 248** on a **Fedora 34** Linux computer.

```
[root@laptop ~]# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 34 (Thirty Four)
[root@laptop ~]# machinectl --version
systemd 248 (v248.3-1.fc34)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX -APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 +PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD +XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified
[root@laptop ~]#
```

It might be possible to use `systemd-run` instead of `machinectl`, but I didn't get that to work.